# ¿Como enviar un JSON por android y leerlo en PHP via "POST" con file_get_contents("php://input");?

Tags: php, android, json, ionic, post

Buen Día Coders...

Les comento mi inconveniente, trabajo en una empresa donde desarrollan bajo IONIC pero quieren migrar una APP a nativo.

En ionic tienen el siguiente código para enviar los datos via post con Angular

```
miMetodo: function(usuario,clave,token){
      // ruta a enviar
      url = 'http://URL/ruta/miFichero.php';
      // JSON con los datos
      info = {
        "c": clave,
        "t": token
      };
      // se adjunta el usuario por método GET
      urldata = url+'?us='+usuario;
      // se hace la petición GET/POST
      return $http.post(urldata,info,{cache:false,timeout:15000});
}
```

Y en miFichero.php reciben los parámetros así:

```
<?php
    include_once '../configuration/databaseConf.php';
    $usuario = $_GET['us'];
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $clave = md5($request->c);
    $token = $request->t;

    // ...
```

Acá el asunto es, que el **PHP NO SE PUEDE MODIFICAR** por lo que en la app Android también es necesario enviar el JSON como se hace en IONIC y debe poder leerse con el método `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");` en PHP.

He  buscado y encuentro soluciones para enviar el JSON como un parámetro vía POST, pero se necesita una `clave->valor`  sin embargo en IONIC (Angular) o en JQuery **NO** se envían los JSON con `clave->valor`, sino que se hace directamente como data POST.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?, a enviar el JSON y que pueda ser leído con el PHP ya existente.

Se los agradezco inmensamente.

Comment: La cuestión sería construir el JSON con la misma estructura con que se construía en Ionic pero desde Android y enviarlo al servidor. Puedes usar `Volley` para eso. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344904/5587982).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer un web service puedes puedes apoyarte de librerias que te ayudan a leer/enviar los datos desde Android por ejemplo:

- Volley: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/
- Android Asynchronous Http Client: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Acá un ejemplo que puede servirte de ayuda:

```
Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            postData.put("name", name.getText().toString());
            postData.put("address", address.getText().toString());
            postData.put("manufacturer", manufacturer.getText().toString());
            postData.put("location", location.getText().toString());
            postData.put("type", type.getText().toString());
            postData.put("deviceID", deviceID.getText().toString());

            new SendDeviceDetails().execute("http://52.88.194.67:8080/IOTProjectServer/registerDevice", postData.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias, logré resolverlo, pero tu implementación consume menos código, la elegiré como aceptada. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya ayudado, suerte y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Lo resolví**

logré hacer lo que requería, después de unir como 100 fuentes distintas. les comento el código que utilicé y reuní para hacer el correcto funcionamiento:

Se los dejo para quién necesite utilizar el código:

```
package apps.miEmpresa.com.co.miApp.services;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Services {
    /**
     * Variable estática que define hacia donde se apuntarán los servicios en la app
     * */
    private final String URL;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase
     * */
    public Services() {
        URL = "http://URL/ruta/";
    }

    /**
     * Método que consulta el estado de sesión del usuario que intenta ingresar a la APP
     * @param usuario usuario con la que iniciará sesión el usuario
     * @param password el password del usuario
     * @return Devuelve el estado en que se encuentra el usuario
     * */
    public String validaLogin(final String usuario, final String password) {

        /*
        Se agrega la dependencia de URL a consultar en el servidor con parámetros GET (opcionales)
        Inicia la variable resultado con un msj de error en caso de que falle la clausula try
        para que se adjunte el resultado a las clausulas catch
         */
        final String url = URL + "miFichero.php?us=" + usuario;
        String resultado = "Ha ocurrido un error function Services.ValidaLogin(): ";
        try {

            // Se crea el JSON a enviar con el password del usuario y el token de firebase
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("c", password);
            jsonObject.put("t", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId());

            /*
            Se crea la petición POST
            se adjunta el JSON creado con sus respectivas cabeceras
             */
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF8"));
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Se ejecuta la petición y se optiene el resultado
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // re retorna el resultado
            return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            // En caso de algún inconveniente se captura el evento y se retorna con el valor inical de error
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return resultado + e.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return resultado + e.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return resultado + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return resultado + e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Y Luego en mi main_activity llamo esa clase y métodos de la siguiente manera:

```
Services servicios = new Services();
String resultado = servicios.validaLogin(tf_usuario.getText().toString(), tf_passwd.getText().toString());

switch (resultado) {
    case "exit":
          ...
          ...
          ...
```